# send MMS via http request

Tags: android, mms

I'm finding a simply way to send MMS via my own application.

I understood that MMS is simple http post request, so it's possible with mobile data to send data to MMS URL Sender ?

What is the problem ? Do you have a pcap  from MMS request or exemple code (java) to do this ?

Thanks, sorry for my english i'm french.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, sending MMS is HTTP POST-ing message encoded according to OMA (Open Mobile Alliance) MMS encoding, also known as MM1 interface. It's a bit complicated, but manageable, you can find spec on OMA site.

Here's java sample with a message dump I developed for one project:

```
    MM1PDU sendReq = new MM1PDU();
    sendReq.setMmsVersion(MM1PDU.MMS_V10);
    sendReq.setMessageType(MessageType.SEND_REQ);
    sendReq.setFrom(new OMAAddress("foo@bar.com"));
    sendReq.setSubject("Test send");
    sendReq.addTo(new OMAAddress("joe@test.com"));
    sendReq.setMessageClass(MessageClass.PERSONAL);
    sendReq.setDeliveryReport(DeliveryReport.NO);
    sendReq.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
    sendReq.setTransactionId("01");
    sendReq.setExpiry(new RelativeDate(2 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    sendReq.setContentType(new MimeType("text/plain; charset=utf-8"));
    sendReq.setContent("Hello world!".getBytes("utf-8"));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    sendReq.save(baos);
    baos.close();

    System.out.println(Hex.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
```

Hex output: